# MouseMove Event Missing from properties list for a NumericUpDown control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, numericupdown

I'm using Visual Basic 2010 Express. When I add a NumericUpDown control to a form, the properties listing for events is not showing a MouseMove event. I know that it exists and I can use AddHandler to create a working handler for it, but it just doesn't show up.  It doesn't it show up in the intellisense listing either.

Is there a way to "refresh" the Visual Studio so that it's included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code of the UpDownBase control from which it inherits from:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
[Browsable(false)]
public new event MouseEventHandler MouseMove
```

Microsoft decided not to make it public.  The reason being, I would guess, is that it just doesn't make sense to do anything with a MouseMove event on that control.  It is a composite control comprised of a TextBox and some buttons.

If exposing that event is important, you would have to inherit from the NumericUpDown control and expose the event yourself:

```
public class MyUpDown : NumericUpDown {

  [Browsable(true)]
  [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
  public new event MouseEventHandler MouseMove {
    add { base.MouseMove += value; }
    remove { base.MouseMove -= value; }
  }
}
```

And the VB.Net version:

```
Public Class MyUpDown
  Inherits NumericUpDown

  <Browsable(True)> _
  <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)> _
  Public Shadows Event MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)

  Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseMove(e As MouseEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseMove(e)
    RaiseEvent MouseMove(Me, e)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The add {} and remove{} lines should reference "base.MouseMove", not "this.MouseMove" otherwise it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that even if you set `MouseMove` and `MouseLeave` events to `NumericUpDown` control, they are will not working properly. And if you really want to handle `NumericUpDown`'s text box mouse events, you should set it to a second element of `NumericUpDown`'s `Controls` collection (it'll be `TextBox` part).

Like this (C# syntax):

```cs
myNumericUpDown->Controls[1]->MouseLeave += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::myNumericUpDown_MouseLeave);
myNumericUpDown->Controls[1]->MouseMove += gcnew System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventHandler(this, &Form1::myNumericUpDown_MouseMove);
```